# If statement in build using ymal aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, if-statement, yaml, aws-codebuild

Hey I'm trying to do an if statement in Yaml, something like
`if $NUMBER_OF_SOURCES == 3 then echo 1`
(echo 1 will change I the future to a script that does something in aws )
what's the correct syntax?
is it even possible?
Hey I'm trying to do an if statement in Yaml,
something like this:
if

```
$NUMBER_OF_SOURCES == 3 then echo 1
```

(echo 1 will change I the future to a script that does something in aws ),
what's the correct syntax? is it even possible?
tried to do something like that but i get

```
      - if [ $NUMBER_OF_SOURCES -eq 3 ]
      - then
        - echo "true"
      - fi
```

> [Container] 2022/04/24 10:35:36 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: if [ $NUMBER_OF_SOURCES -eq 3 ]. Reason: exit status 2

Comment: YAML is not a programming language and doesn't have statements. You can do this inside some script embedded in a YAML file, or possibly using AWS templating, but you need to describe what you want to do in a lot more detail for us to be able to help you.

Comment: What is your buidspec.yml?

Comment: basically im going to need to do if Nubmer_OF_Sources == 3 then - test -d $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/src/config || mkdir $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/src/config
      - cp -R $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_sourceConfigArtifact/* $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/src/config @flyx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this using pipe (`|`) notation in `yaml`:

```
      - |
        if [ $NUMBER_OF_SOURCES -eq 3 ]
        then
          echo "true"
        fi
```

or just put everything in one line:

```
      - if [ $NUMBER_OF_SOURCES -eq 3 ]; then echo "true"; fi
```